# Numbers: Line graphs for cell values across multiple worksheets

Tags: numbers, graph

I want to create a line graph whose reference data is across **multiple** worksheets.
For example: I have 5 different worksheets (named W1 to W5)
In each of the worksheet, a specific cell (Ex: B2) in a specific table (Ex: Tab_Summary) is of interest to me.
I want to plot a line graph to show trends of (Tab_Summary:B2) across each of the worksheets W1 to W5.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone knows how to source data from multiple table inputs, but I just use brute force and make one table that contains all data I need to chart. Tables can refer to data from multiple other tables, so now with your charting data in one table, charting becomes a snap.